# How to set different background colors to multiple UITableViewCells according to different events?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm working on time comparison. What I hope to achieve is to change cell colors according to the comparison results.

For example, I have a list of three event times: 10, 11, 12. They are set to three different table view cells.

cell 1: 10

cell 2: 11

cell 3: 12

The current time is also 11.

**I need to achieve:**

event time < current time (past), set cell color to red.

event time == current time (now), set cell color to green.

event time > current time (not yet), set cell color to blue.

*It should make cell 1: red / cell 2: green / cell 3: blue*

**The Issue:** cell color only changes in cell 1. Cell 2 and cell3 will also be changed to cell 1's color.

**My Code:**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return [event1,event2,event3].count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let myCell = eventTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("event", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    myCell.textLabel?.text = [event1,event2,event3][indexPath.row]


    if past 
    {
       myCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    }
    else if now
    {
        myCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    }
    else if notyet
    {
       myCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    }

    return myCell
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!!!

Comment: How are these "times" represented? Are they strings, dates, integers?

Comment: I'm using strings. I should probably set them to integers. But I don't think that would change the issue here. @JoshCaswell

Comment: I think the issue might be caused by using the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier. Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: What are past, now, and notyet? Where and how are they calculated?

Comment: @rmaddy
`past, now, notyet = false;

if(event1 < event2)
{
    past = true;
}`

Comment: But where is that code? You need to check the condition for the given index path in the `cellForRowAt` method.

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you for the help. The code for past,now,notyet is inside ViewDidLoad. Are you suggesting Shayan Jalil's answer?

Comment: @WoShiNiBaBa No, that code is wrong too. Since "current time" changes constantly, you need to determine a cell's color in `cellForRowAt` based on the event time for the given index path and the current time. You can't do any calculations ahead of time.

Comment: @rmaddy What if I just use the hour value? The current time will be the same for an hour. Could you please give me an example in code of what you suggested?